# Change the color of "Availability: In stock " depending the quantity from the stock?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, stock

I changed the color of "Availability: In stock" in green but i want to change the color "Availability: In stock" programmly.
For example

if the quantity of product  < 5 i want to color "Availability: In
stock" in red

if the quantity of product  > 5 and the quantity of
product < 10, i want to color "Availability: In stock" in orange

if the quantity of product  > 5 and the quantity of product <
 10, i want to color "Availability: In stock" in green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the available qty like this

```
$qty = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

But you have to be careful. You can have products where the line above returns 0 but the product is in stock because `Manage stock` is set to `No`.
To check this use:

```
$manageStock = $_product->getStockItem()->getManageStock();
```

Now combining these 2 you can get the color like this:

```
$manageStock = $_product->getStockItem()->getManageStock();

if (!$manageStock) { 
    $color = 'green'; //forever in stock
}
else {
    $qty = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
    if ($qty < 5){
        $color = 'red';
    }
    elseif ($qty < 10) {
        $color = 'orange';
    }
    else {
        $color = 'green';
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Now change the element that wraps the availability to this:

```
<p class="availability in-stock <?php echo $color?>">
```

and add this to your css file

```
p.green{color:green}
p.orange{color:orange}
p.red{color:red}
```

note: This works for simple products.

Comment: I must use css to change the color

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: I will added this code in this file app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\simple.php in a function ?

Comment: @Amirov You can add it directly in the template. It's easier and you don't have to override classes.

Comment: I confused with other things thank you that's work

Answer (score 0):

Would you know how to implement this in magento 2.4?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/209214)