# (Configurable products) Change the color of “Availability: In stock ” depending the quantity from the stock?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, products, stock

I have to make something like this:

[Change the color of "Availability: In stock " depending the quantity from the stock?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/change-the-color-of-availability-in-stock-depending-the-quantity-from-the-st/8471#8471)

but I've configurable products.

What's the way?
Thanks

Comment: You are using default configuration for managing stock for configurable product, or, you're using "Manage Stock"?

Comment: I'm using "Manage Stock"

Comment: You need to make the change at design level, i.e. in phtml files under template

Comment: Uhm, about which file specificaly do you speak?

Comment: app/design/frontend/YOUR_PKG/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Answer (score 2):

You could override [`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php) to include the qtys of the associated products, then extend the JavaScript function [Product.reloadPrice()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/js/varien/configurable.js#L272) to also update the CSS class of the availability element based on the respective qty.